# Acer Aspire 5542G overheating with ubuntu/kubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, acer

I have an Acer Aspire 5542G laptop purchased couple of years ago. All these days, i used windows 7 on it . Then I tried ubuntu 12.04 . Everything was fine except the overheating issue. I updated ubuntu with all security fixes and available updates but nothing solved the problem. With idle use like internet browsing, the cpu fan speeds up a lot and i can feel very hot air coming from the vent (comparable to playing serious 3d game in windows). But it will not go to a point of freeze and shutdown. But as long as im using it, with no intensive tasks at all, the laptop stays too hot. This wasn't the case with windows7. In windows 7 the fan will not rotate at all with normal use.

I heard there was manufacturing defect with some acer laptops, but i think it wasn't the case with my laptop since windows7 runs perfectly.

I updated the bios to latest version. I cleaned dust in the vents. I tried kubuntu 12.04 up-to-date. Nothing solved the issue.

- My laptop specs are:
- **CPU :** AMD turion2 x2 M500 @ 2.2GHz
- **GPU :** AMD Mobility Radeon HD4570
- 3GB RAM and 320GB hard disk.  
     **EDIT : ** If it helps, my laptop was shipped with LINPUS LINUX.

Answer (score 1):

I guess i found something. It overheats when using the open source radeon driver. After installing fglrx and setting the power save option in catalyst control center there seems to be major difference.

Answer (score 1):

The overheating I don't think is 100% due to driver/OS support. Ours was overheating and freezing in Windows 7 a while back. We ended up replacing the laptop anyways since my wife was using it a lot more than we anticipated so we wanted something a little more robust. Recently I took the 5542G out to see if I could get it up and running with Windows 8 and also to see if would work well enough for our 4 year old daughter. Needless to say, it was still overheating in W8.

After a bit of research, it looks like the main culprit was the heatsink was lifting off of the CPU/GPU due to bad thermal compound. I found a service manual online (don't have the link handy unfortunately), took the laptop apart, cleaned the old paste off and replaced it with some Arctic Silver. Reseated the heatsink, put it all together, and it seemed to do the trick. Before doing all that, I was hitting temps over 90C while idle. Now, I'm getting closer to 40C and not much higher under load.

Comment: I do not have the heat sink issue you mentioned. Apart from the hardware faults the open source radeon driver in Linux cannot do power savings efficiently (currently).  Hence installing fglrx will make a big change.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd keep an eye on the heatsink in the future. It looks like it was a fairly common problem. Mind you, mine had the Athlon II triple-core, not the Turion, so it might be isolated to the Athlons only.

Answer (score -1):

Certa vez li em um forum que este problema ocorre com o desenvolvimento da gestão de energia do Ubuntu.
Tenho o mesmo notebook e o mesmo problema.
Vamos aguardar para ver se um dia alguem resolve.

Comment: Sad to hear that. Next time, i would buy a pc/laptop with linux out of the box. But for now i really hope this issue gets solved.